# Rubber composition A13 B13 C20 F17 K11 L14

Tags: polymers, materials, identification

I am looking at a rubber compound with the following description:

**A13 B13 C20 F17 K11 L14**

I cannot find the meaning for "A" and "L".

I am not a chemist.

Comment: I don't think either of those are elements.

Comment: Whatever it is it does not make sense as a chemical formula.

Comment: @M.A.R. These are not *chemical* elements. It looks like they are ASTM D2000 specs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with chemistry. Just because something looks like a chemical formula to some laymen does not mean it is one. The answer confirms the suspicion.

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR** I think you might need two more things to interpret this line: the first code part of the standard, and the standard itself - ASTM D2000 (needs to be purchased).

---

These descriptors are not *chemical* elements, they seem to be the part of [ASTM D2000](https://www.astm.org/Standards/D2000.htm) "Standard Classiﬁcation System for Rubber Products in Automotive Applications", so what you are looking at is the suffix part of the full spec, which is [usually written as](http://www.emtengineering.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Barry-Controls-FAQ-ASTM-D2000.pdf):

[image]

The part after ASTM D2000 includes information about units of measure, grade durometer hardness and tensile strength. This is a rather essential sequence and if you don't have it it is impossible to define the exact meaning of the given suffix, which are:

**A**: Heat resistance;
**B**: Compression set, standard test specimen cut from a slab;
**C**: Ozone or weather resistance;
**F**: Low-temperature resistance;
**K**: Adhesion;
**L**: is not explicitly defined in D2000−12, probably falls into **Z**: *Any special requirement, which shall be specified in detail*.

> Each suffix letter should preferably be followed by two suffix numbers [...] The first suffix number always indicates the test method; time of test is part of the method [...]. The second suffix number, if used, always indicates the temperature of test [...]. Where three-digit numbers are required, they are separated by a dash.

Exact characteristics of the rubber can be found in numerous tables from ASTM D2000-12 datasheet, but without having the first part of the descriptor there is not much to be done.

The exact set of suffixes you provided can be found in [this report](http://mwrsf.unl.edu/researchhub/files/Report278/TRP-03-281-13.pdf), the rubber they refer to is **ASTM D2000 5AA425 A13 B13 C20 F17 K11 L14** used for shock absorbers.